# Android Why cannot use TextView in Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, toolbar

I am using a custom toolbar layout with a TextView in ToolBar
But when I run it 
It hint that

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fish.sevenseconds/com.goldfish.sevenseconds.activities.Addmem}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

this is my Activity code

```
toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.square_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

This is my xml

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/admem_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/khaki"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/silver"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: your toolbar id is missmatched.......use `toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.admem_toolbar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheeck the below code change the id to match the xml for findviewbyid for toolbar

```
toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.admem_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

XML

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/admem_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/khaki"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/silver"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```